# Form submission PHP ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am setting up a form submission and having some troubles getting the Ajax to connect to the PHP and send the form info to the desired email address. Not an expert at this whole thing as its the first time I attempt AJAX to submit a form information.

Any input on what is going wrong is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**THIS CODE IS NOW ALL WORKING** I have updated the question with the new code.

**FORM:**

```
    <form name="contactform" id="contactsubmit" action="form_action.php">
        <h2>contact form</h2>
        <hr>
        <label class="Tgrey">name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        <label class="Tgrey">email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        <label class="Tgrey">Telephone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="Tgrey">Telephone</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50" id="message" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
```

**JQUERY/AJAX**

```
$("form").submit(function(e)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    {
        'url' : $(this).attr('action'),
        'type' : "POST",
        'data' : $(this).serialize(),
        success:function(success)
        {alert("HEY")},
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
   if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['telephone'], $_POST['message'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to  = "name@email.com";
    $subject = "Message from $name via Web:";
    $txt = "This message has come website: \n
    $message \n
    Contact details:\n 
    Name: $name, Email: $email, Telephone: $telephone";
    $header = "From Website";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
}
```

Comment: FYI sidenote: `<form>` does not hold the name attribute. Then this will fail `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` - Check your console and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The PHP-code won't be executed, as there's no form element with the _name_ 'submit', so `isset($_POST['submit'])` returns false.

Comment: You also have nothing assigned to `$headers`. Again... error reporting.

Comment: oh, and all these `isset($_POST` will also fail. You're probably trying to use a ternary operator, but just the wrong way. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - However, best to use `!empty()` and in a ternary.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. I started from scratch with the input you gave me and got it working. The code above has been updated

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['submit']` is not sent in the serialized form data. What you should do is check to see if the POST array has got data in it:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {.. // if not empty, proceed
```

If you didn't want to change your PHP you could append `&submit=submit` to your variable holding the serialized data in your AJAX function:

```
'data' : $(this).serialize() + '&submit=submit',
```

In addition, as @Fred -ii- pointed out, you have some variables which are not set(`$subject` *(this is also missing from your form unless you intend to set it in the code)* and `$headers`). You need to add some basic error checking to your scripts which will indicate these problems. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: You're welcome @AdamKhouryDesign Since this helped you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is my simple solution

**HTML**

```
<span id="message"></span>

<form id="form" action="add.php" method="post">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">

    <input type="submit" name="addUser">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
frm = $('#form');

frm.submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        type: frm.attr('method'),

        // adds &addUser in the end of data
        // firstname=value1&lastname=value2&addUser
        data: frm.serialize()+'&'+frm.children(':submit').attr('name'),
        success: function(res) {
            $('#message').html(res);
            frm.trigger("reset");
        }
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

include 'database.php';

if (isset($_POST['addUser'])) {
    $firstname= $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname= $_POST['lastname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```