# How to use jquery function and isset() together via a submit button?

Tags: php, jquery

First I have a row and a submit button on a table like this:

```
 <tr id="date">
      <td class="left" valign="top">
         <label>Some content: </label>
      </td>
      <td class="right">
          <? if ($akis_kademe == "ekle") { ?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit5"  class="btn" value="Tarih ekle" />
          <? } ?>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

And isset method...

```
if(isset($submit5)){
               ?>
    <tr id="ek_takvim">
          <td class="left" valign="top">        
          </td>
          <td class="right">   
          </td>
    </tr> 

 <?  }?>
```

Jquery function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("submit5").click(function(){
        $(ek_takvim).hide();
    });
});
```

All I wanna do that when I click the button I wanna add isset section on my table and also hide the button at the same time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but none the less, you do know that only through AJAX can you "execute" php functions through jQuery / JS calls?

Comment: You can set assign id or class to that section and use .show() function.'$(".myclass").show();'

Comment: *" I wanna add isset section on my table"*, sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by **add isset section**?

Comment: I **think** he/she want to add the element `#ek_takvim` after `#date` and hide `input[name=submit5]`. 

Right?

Comment: you re right @Glufu

Comment: ## Here is the solution ## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569407/form-submission-php-ajax/64591649#64591649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you add the row `ek_takvim` right after the button row and hide them by css or onLoad-Event. Then this will do the rest of the work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=submit5]‌").click(function(){
        $("#ek_takvim").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

I like this approach more:

HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="submit5" onclick="goodFunctionName()"  class="btn" value="Tarih ekle" />
```

JS

```
function goodFunctionName(){
    $("#ek_takvim").show();
    $("input[name=submit5]").hide();
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c0f7bn96/

Talk to me: https://jsfiddle.net/c0f7bn96/#&togetherjs=5BxtqPPlE1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
<?php $takvimDisplay =  isset($submit5)?"block":"none"; ?>
<tr id="ek_takvim" style="display:<?php echo $takvimDisplay ?>">
      <td class="left" valign="top">        
      </td>
      <td class="right">   
      </td>
</tr> 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=submit5]‌").click(function(){
        $("#ek_takvim").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```